# Lubuntu screen shifted to right suddenly while working

Tags: lubuntu, screen

[image: Here is the screenshot for the same]

I am using Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. My display suddenly shifted to right while working.The lock screen is fine. But the problem persists for desktop and every application. It's a laptop so there is no display adjust options as mentioned in other posts. It is also not a problem of screen from hardware perspective as the lock screen is fine.

Answer (score 3):

I just right clicked on the panel present in the left side and then deleted it using the option that popped up after right clicking.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted after two days from now by clicking the gray checkmark beside your answer which will change its color from gray to green.

Comment: Prior to deleting did you notice a name / application of that weird looking left panel window?